# Не обновляется класс R

Tags: android, eclipse

Проблема  с обновлением класса R: в настройках стоит P`roject->Build Automatically`
пробовал `Project->Clean`  и построить заново, но увы... что еще можно сделать?

Comment: измени что нибудь в любом xml файле и сохрани, R файл должен сам сгенерироваться

Comment: пробовал не реагирует третий раз проект создаю ...

Comment: ошибка, гдето в.  хмлках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На днях сам мучался с этой проблемой, поэтому опишу подробнее, хотя [Gorets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3608/gorets) прав в своем комментарии.

Если у тебя стоит галочка в **Project->Build Automatically** и **Project->Clean** не помогает, то скорее всего существует ошибка в xml файле. Это может быть из-за разметки не по правилам грамматики, либо вы используете стороннюю библиотеку и линк на нее в проекте умер, проверить можно выбрав папку проекта и в контекстном меню выбрав **Properties->Android** в самом низу есть окошко для выбора библиотеки. Помни, что проекты Android 4.х могут не поддерживать чистую jar библиотеку, придется создавать отдельный проект библиотеки и ссылаться на него.

Если ты исправили все xml, а R класса все равно нет, то проверь java код, возможно где-то импорт R класса твоего проекта заменился на android.R .

Если даже это не помогло, то попробуй создать dummy.xml.

Если и это не помогло, то придется вспоминать какие ресурсы ты добавлял последними в **assets/** и **drawable/**, очень редко дело может крыться в них и придется их удалить.

P.S. Не забывай между этапами выполнять стандартную процедуру: **F5** по папке проекта, затем **Project->Clean**.